# How to filter out a certain portion of ./gradlew project:dependencies command?

Tags: shell, gradle, awk, sed

Our build.gradle files have your normal `depndencies` block, like so..

```
dependencies {
    compile("com.myco.service:service-discovery:+")
    compile("com.myco.common:some-common:1.0.84")
    compile("com.myco.cms:cms-service-client:1.0.145")
    compile("com.myco.stats:some123-stats-service-client:1.0.140")
    ...
}
```

I run this to get the dependency tree

```
$ ./gradlew project:dependencies | grep com\.myco | sort | uniq
```

and get

```
+--- com.myco.canam:canam:0.1.4
+--- com.myco.cms:cms-service-client:1.0.145 (*)
+--- com.myco.common:some-common:1.0.84
+--- com.myco.crm:crm.ansira:0.0.1
+--- com.myco.somehtml:somehtmlcleaner:0.0.1
|         +--- com.myco.common:some-common:1.0.79 -> 1.0.84 (*)
|         +--- com.myco.security:security-service-client:1.0.107 -> 1.0.134 (*)
|    +--- com.myco.common:some-common:1.0.58 -> 1.0.84 (*)
|    +--- com.myco.common:some-common:1.0.80 -> 1.0.84 (*)
```

I want to get ALL the lines that do not start with the `|` character. It just so happens that all these lines also end with `(*)` characters, so I add a `sed` pipe, like so

```
./gradlew project:dependencies | sed 's/^.* //' | grep com\.myco | sort | uniq
```

and get

```
com.myco.canam:canam:0.1.4
com.myco.common:some-common:1.0.84
com.myco.crm:crm.ansira:0.0.1
com.myco.somehtml:somehtmlcleaner:0.0.1
```

which is exactly what I want, **except** that this line is missing

```
com.myco.cms:cms-service-client:1.0.145
```

**because** it so happens to end with the `(*)` characters. What is a better sed (or awk) expression so I get

```
com.myco.canam:canam:0.1.4
com.myco.cms:cms-service-client:1.0.145
com.myco.common:some-common:1.0.84
com.myco.crm:crm.ansira:0.0.1
com.myco.somehtml:somehtmlcleaner:0.0.1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like this might be what you want (using `cat file` instead of `./gradlew project:dependencies` since I don't have that command):

```
$ cat file | awk '/^\+.*com\.myco/ && !seen[$2]++{print $2}'
com.myco.canam:canam:0.1.4
com.myco.cms:cms-service-client:1.0.145
com.myco.common:some-common:1.0.84
com.myco.crm:crm.ansira:0.0.1
com.myco.somehtml:somehtmlcleaner:0.0.1
```

Comment: So how do I pipe that in the my `./gradlew...` command? Use it in place of the `sed`?

Comment: `./gradlew... | awk 'script'` instead of `awk 'script' file`. I updated my answer to state that. You don't need any other pipes or commands, just awk.