# How to filter out a certain portion of ./gradlew project:dependencies command? (version 2)

Tags: bash, shell, gradle, awk, sed

I posted [How to filter out a certain portion of ./gradlew project:dependencies command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57700382/how-to-filter-out-a-certain-portion-of-gradlew-projectdependencies-command) a while back and implemented the accepted answer given. However it seems like it's giving me the wrong info.

I have the following (simplified) `build.gradle` file

```
dependencies {
    implementation("com.myco.security:security-service-client:1.0.199")
}
```

When I run the command

```
$ ./gradlew :project:dependencies | tee deps.txt
```

I seen the following in the `deps.txt` file, abbreviated to show only the artifact I want.

```
compileClasspath - Compile classpath for source set 'main'.
+--- com.myco.security:security-service-client:1.0.199 -> 1.0.148
+--- com.myco.security:security-service-client:1.0.148 (*)
default - Configuration for default artifacts.
+--- com.myco.security:security-service-client:1.0.199 -> 1.0.148
+--- com.myco.security:security-service-client:1.0.148 (*)
+--- com.myco.security:security-service-client:1.0.148 (*)
implementation - Implementation only dependencies for source set 'main'. (n)
+--- com.myco.security:security-service-client:1.0.199 (n)
+--- com.myco.security:security-service-client:1.0.148 (n)
runtimeClasspath - Runtime classpath of source set 'main'.
+--- com.myco.security:security-service-client:1.0.199 -> 1.0.148
testCompileClasspath - Compile classpath for source set 'test'.
+--- com.myco.security:security-service-client:1.0.199 -> 1.0.148
+--- com.myco.security:security-service-client:1.0.148 (*)
testRuntimeClasspath - Runtime classpath of source set 'test'.
+--- com.myco.security:security-service-client:1.0.199 -> 1.0.148
+--- com.myco.security:security-service-client:1.0.148 (*)
```

IOW, the dependency in my `build.gradle` file appears multiple times. Now if I apply the answer in my original linked post, I get

```
com.myco.security:security-service-client:1.0.199
com.myco.security:security-service-client:1.0.148
```

as the artifact, instead just the following, which is what I want to match the dependency in my `build.gradle` file.

```
com.myco.security:security-service-client:1.0.199
```

How can I improve the `awk` command in my linked post? IOW

```
cat deps.txt | awk '/^\+.*com\.myco/ && !seen[$2]++{print $2}' | some_other_cmd
```

Should only give me

```
com.myco.security:security-service-client:1.0.199
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this awk:

```
awk -F '[: ]+' -v OFS=: '/^\+.*com\.myco/ && !seen[$2,$3]++{print $2, $3, $4}' deps.txt
```

```
com.myco.security:security-service-client:1.0.199
```

**Details:**

- Using `-F '[: ]+'` we split columns on space or colon
- Using `-v OFS=:` we use colon as output file separator
- `seen[$2,$3]` uses `group:module` of dependency as array key
- `print $2, $3, $4` prints `group:module:version`

Comment: Thanks @anubhava, you da man! This worked like a charm. ONE day I'll learn awk properly.