# How to filter out a certain portion of ./gradlew project:dependencies command? (version 3)

Tags: awk, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

This is an updated question for [How to filter out a certain portion of ./gradlew project:dependencies command? (version 2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59291987/how-to-filter-out-a-certain-portion-of-gradlew-projectdependencies-command)

I'm writing a routine that parses the `dependencies{}` portion of a `build.gradle` file, which may look like this

```
dependencies {
  compile "com.groupId:artifact0:1.0.0"
  compile "com.groupId:artifact1:2.+"
  compile "com.groupId:artifact3:3.+"
  compile "org.otherGroupId:artifact:1.0.0"
}
```

Now I run a Jenkins pipeline (Groovy) script that does the following. The `awk` takes all the lines that start with "+" character in column 1, and has "com.groupId" string. What I'm calling "other data" are lines that neither have "+" in column 1, nor the "com.groupId" string, the `awk` script ignores those.

```
sh "./gradlew project:dependencies | tee deps.txt"
List depList = sh(script: " awk -F '[: ]+' -v OFS=: '/^\\+.*com\\.groupId/ && !seen[\$2,\$3]++{print \$2, \$3, \$4}' deps.txt",
                  returnStdout: true).split("\n")
```

My `deps.txt` shows

```
+ --- com.groupId:artifact0:1.0.0
... other data
+ --- com.groupId:artifact1:2.+ -> 2.1.0
... other data
+ --- com.groupId:artifact2:3.+ -> 3.0.0 (*)
... other data
+ --- org.otherGroupId:artifact:1.0.0
... other data
```

and my `List depList` looks like

```
com.groupId:artifact0:1.0.0
com.groupId:artifact1:2.+
com.groupId:artifact2:3.+
```

which is exactly what I asked `awk` to do correct? Note the 4th dependency is not there, again because of my `awk` statement.

But how can I modify the `awk` script to get the actual version values, so my `depList` shows this? In other words, I want it to get the resolved versions obtained by the `dependencies` Gradle task.

```
com.groupId:artifact0:1.0.0
com.groupId:artifact1:2.1.0
com.groupId:artifact2:3.0.0
```

Comment: You might want to start with a question that's just "how do I do X in awk" and then later ask a followup of "how do I call my awk script from Y" if you can't figure that part out rather than going straight for "how do I write an awk script to do X when called from Y" because the latter requires someone who knows both awk and Y well to provide the right answer.

Comment: I know your question is about how to use `awk` but you could accomplish what you want without using `awk` or any external tool outside of Gradle.  If you post a question asking how to output a list of resolved versions in the format you like, that could be answered as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```sh
awk '!/^\+.*com\.groupId/ {next} {dep = $2}
NF >= 4 && $3 == "->" {sub(/:[^:]+$/, ":" $4, dep)} {print dep}' deps.txt

com.groupId:artifact0:1.0.0
com.groupId:artifact1:2.1.0
com.groupId:artifact2:3.0.0
```

**Details:**

- we skip all lines that don't start with `+` and contains `com.groupId` since we only want `com.groupId` dependencies
- Store `$2` in variable `dep`
- If there are >= 4 fields and `$3` is `->` then substitute last after `:` with value of `$4`
- Finally we print `dep`

Comment: This didn't work for me, that is, I get no output. My exact command line is (I have to escape the `$` characters for Jenkins pipeline) `awk '!/^+/ {next} {dep = \$3} NF >= 5 && \$4 == "->" {sub(/:[^:]+\$/, ":" \$5, dep)} {print dep}' deps.txt`

Comment: Does it have to be escaped inside single quotes also? Can you test this `awk` command as is in your shell first?

Comment: my `deps.txt` file has a lot of lines in it (that's why I didn't post it), but the lines starting with `+` AND containing `com.groupId` are what I want. If I just run your `awk` command on a shell window, it doesn't give me the output I need.

Comment: Can you try my updated awk command on your `deps.txt`. I have my dependencies generated using `gradle 7.0`. Let me know which version are you using?

Comment: We use a really old version (lonnnng story). `Gradle 3.4.1` Thanks!

Comment: anubhava, I updated my post. You actually answered the earlier post I referred to.

Comment: anubhava, I updated your answer to filter out the lines I need even more.

Comment: @ChrisF: Thanks so much for your edit. I just came back online in my morning time.

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you want:

```
$ awk -F'[ :]+' -v OFS=':' '$1=="+"{ sub(/ \(.*/,""); print $3, $4, $(NF) }' deps.txt
com.groupId:artifact0:1.0.0
com.groupId:artifact1:2.1.0
com.groupId:artifact2:3.0.0
```

if you were just asking how to turn deps.txt from your question into the above output using awk.

Comment: I don't get an output from this either. My command line is `awk -F'[ :]+' -v OFS=':' '\$1=="+"{ sub(/ \\(.*/,""); print \$3, \$4, \$(NF) }' deps.txt` (I had to escape the `$` to run in a pipeline)

Comment: You have 2 separate questions - A) How do I do X in awk, and B) how to I call awk from Y where Y is "Jenkins" or "Groovy" or whatever that system is you mentioned. This answers "A", I'm sorry but I can't help you with "B" as I've no idea what those things are (which is why I suggested you ask 2 separate questions).

Comment: Thanks, but actually I just have one question, that is, how to modify my existing `awk` script to get the output I want from a file I generate from a Gradle command.

Comment: Divide and conquer goes a long way. Good luck.